# how to fetch and display images from database in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

i'm trying to load a list of wallpapers from local storage that i already post them  and saved their paths in mongoDB.

So i'm trying to loop through the array of paths and use each path as  src in each img tag

the main.js component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        data : []
    }
    componentDidMount(){

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/').then(res => res.json())
        .then(data=> this.setState({data}))

    }
    render() {

        console.log(this.state.data)

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Main</h1>
                {this.state.data ? this.state.data.map(img => 
(<div key={img._id}>{img ? <img src={require(`${img.img.path}`)} 
alt={img.img.name}/>:<span>deleted</span>}</div>)): 
<h3>loading</h3>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the server code :

```
  server.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        Wallpaper.find({}, (err, result)=>{
            if(err) {
                res.json({msg: err})
            }else{
                res.json(result)
            }
        })
    })
```

it should return the images in the uploads folder in the react app but it returns this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ahdy/Workspace/Wally/wallcraft/public/uploads/ak47456193147469824_n.jpg'
```

Comment: Why the `require()` call? If those images are in some folder on the server, just the `src` directly to their URL.

Comment: `this.state.data ?` will be true anyways, use `this.state.data.length ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
<img src={require(`${img.img.path}`)}
```

should be

```
<img src={`/uploads/${img.img.path}`}
```

no need of `require` here

NB: put correct path there

Comment: thanks i fixed it like you mentioned but instead of img.path i used img.name